# Integration using the Parseval-Plancherel identity

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

I need to integrate $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sigma(\lambda)\theta(2\Lambda-2)]\,\mathrm{d}\Lambda$$
where the function $\theta(x)=-2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{c}\right)$. And the Fourier transform of the Function $\sigma(x)$ is given by:
$\tilde\sigma(p)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sigma(x)e^{-I x p}\,\mathrm{d}p=e^{-iap}\frac{1}{e^{-c Abs[p]}}$ .

I can quite easily calculate the Fourier transform of $g(\Lambda)=\theta(2\Lambda-2)$ to be $\tilde g(\Lambda)=\frac{e^{-i p} \left(2 i \pi  e^{-\frac{c | p| }{2}}\right)}{p}$.

My question is:

Is the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sigma(\lambda)\theta(2\Lambda-2)]\,\mathrm{d}\Lambda$ equal to $\int_{-\infty}^\infty dp \tilde\sigma(p)\tilde g(p)$?

If not, what may be the good way to solve this integral?

Comment: Is there a typo in the definition of $\theta(x)$?  It has $\frac xx$ in it, and that makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks for finding the typo.

Comment: The integral of their product will equal the convolution of their Fourier transforms evaluated at $0$ (this is true for any Fourier transform, $\int_\Bbb{R} f(x)dx = \hat{f}(0)$) The convolution evaluated at zero is the integral of the product of the two functions, but one of them is flipped.